# HTML Server control and Web Server Control

Tags: asp.net

m new to development and i want to know what is the main thing that differ between web server control and html server control.
they both run at server. Is the only difference is that, html server control are light weight??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! In short:

Difference Between ASP.NET Server Controls,HTML Server Controls and HTML Intrinsic Controls

**ASP.NET Server Controls**
Advantages:

1. ASP .NET Server Controls can however detect the target browser's capabilities and render themselves accordingly. No issues for compatibility issues of Browsers i.e page that might be used by both HTML 3.2 and HTML 4.0 browsers code to be written by you.
2. Newer set of controls that can be used in the same manner as any HTMl control like Calender controls. (No need of Activex Control for doing this which would then bring up issues of Browser compatibility).
3. Processing would be done at the server side. In built functionality to check for few values(with Validation controls) so no need to choose between scripting language which would be incompatible with few browsers.
4. ASP .NET Server Controls have an object model different from the traditional HTML and even provide a set of properties and methods that can change the outlook and behavior of the controls.
5. ASP .NET Server Controls have higher level of abstraction. An output of an ASP .NET server control can be the result of many HTML tags that combine together to produce that control and its events.

Disadvantages:

1. The control of the code is inbuilt with the web server controls so you have no much of direct control on these controls
2. Migration of ASP to any ASP.NET application is difficult. Its equivalent to rewriting your new application

**HTML Server Controls**
Advantages:

1. The HTML Server Controls follow the HTML-centric object model. Model similar to  HTML
2. Here the controls can be made to interact with Client side scripting. Processing would be done at client as well as server depending on your code.
3. Migration of the ASP project thought not very easy can be done by giving each intrinsic HTML control a runat = server to make it HTML Server side control.
4. The HTML Server Controls have no mechanism of identifying the capabilities of the client browser accessing the current page.
5. A HTML Server Control has similar abstraction with its corresponding HTML tag and offers no abstraction.

Disadvantages:
1. You would need to code for the browser compatibility.

**HTML Intrinsic Controls**
Advantages:
1. Model similar to HTML
2. Here the controls can be made to interact with Client side scripting

Disadvantages:
1. You would need to code for the browser compatibility

Happy coding and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

**Server controls** easy to use and manage, but HTML controls are not.

**HTML controls** performance is better then Server controls.